# how do you return a string from an Erlang C node?

Tags: string, erlang

I want to be able to pass in a string - list - into a C node for Erlang and return back a string to the Erlang process after some computation.

```
result = function(input_string),
```

where input_string is of type ETERM *

My computation on the string uses char * variables for strings.

Please let me know if this is sufficient information to go on.

[The C node example in the erl_interface tutorial uses integer input to and output from the C node]

TIA,
BR,
Shailen

Comment: have you considered using a nif? http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html It is easier to implement imo and has a rebar templete which makes even more easier.

Comment: @cashmere, a nif wouldn't suit the requirement that there be several large files to be read into search space but once upon startup, not on every invocation, thanks.

Comment: @ombud a NIF library can specify a `load` function which can write information into its argument `*priv_data`. You can then get a pointer to this data on every NIF invocation using the function named `enif_priv_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `erl_iolist_to_string` for input (every Erlang "string" is also an iolist).

Use `erl_mk_string` instead of `erl_mk_int` for output.

http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_eterm.html#erl_iolist_to_string

http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_eterm.html#erl_mk_string

Comment: Thanks @r3m0t, that should do it.